# Создание сервера в nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Изучаю `node.js`, подскажите чем отличаются эти команды:

```
var server = new http.createServer();
```

от этой

```
var server = http.createServer((req, res) => {}
```

Comment: в первой параметр не передается, а во второй передается

Comment: ``req`` значит ``request``, ``res`` значит ``response``, а значит см. комментарий выше.

Comment: @Grundy а есть еще `http.Server()` просто, а он чем отличается можете сказать? И когда какой лучше использовать или разницы нет? Спасибо.

Comment: Откуда ты это берешь все? :-)

Comment: @Grundy видео уроки кантора)

Comment: А он там разве не объясняет что и когда надо использовать? :-)

Comment: @Grundy нет, там только что это создание сервера

Comment: Возможно далее будет пояснение.

Comment: Собственно все просто: [`http.createServer(...)`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_options_requestlistener) - функция, которая возвращает объект сервера. Возвращаемый объект класса [`http.Server`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_server)

Comment: @Grundy то есть в одном случае я могу использовать сам класс а в другом его объект? и по сути разницы нет что использовать?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91984/discussion-between-grundy-and-asas-sas).